# Many NA values when extracting data from a RasterLayer onto SpatialPolygons

Tags: raster, r

Data used in this post:

- RasterLayer which contains data on Heat Wave Frequency, downloaded from here: https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.898014?format=html#download
- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of European NUTS regions (downloaded from here: https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts)

I would like to extract the mean Heat Wave Frequency per region from the RasterLayer. For this, I used the following command:

```
hwf <- extract(x = HWF, y = NUTS_map, fun = mean, df = TRUE, weights = TRUE, normalizeWeights = TRUE, sp = TRUE)
```

Out of the 1462 regions, there are 392 NAs for the newly created variable Heat Wave Frequency (NAs plotted in blue on the map). The NA values seem to be situated near the edges, so there must be a logical reason for this.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

[image: Plot of the RasterLayer, NUTS map and the missing values]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try again but with `na.rm=TRUE` in `extract`. The default when extracting raster data by polygon is `FALSE`:

```
 ## S4 method for signature 'Raster,SpatialPolygons'
 extract(x, y, fun=NULL, na.rm=FALSE, weights=FALSE, 
    normalizeWeights=TRUE, cellnumbers=FALSE, small=TRUE, df=FALSE, layer, nl, 
    factors=FALSE, sp=FALSE, ...)
```

What's possibly happening is that at least one pixel covered by a polygon has an `NA` value and so the mean will be `NA`. In an ideal world the land polygons would not be over the sea but you have to consider approximations of rasterisation and digitisation.

Not tested, because if I'm looking at the right data file its 275Mb of data download I can't spare right now...